# Tabulator: How to trigger the filter after data is edited/changed

Tags: javascript, tabulator

**Tabulator version: 4.6.3**

Assume the following:

1. Data is loaded successfully into table.
2. Column "status" only knows two values: 1 and 2
3. When header filter is applied with e.g. value 1, everything works nice: rows with status unlike 1 are hidden. As you would expected.
4. When I edit the status of one record to 2 it is stored in database via ajax call but the filter is not working as you would expect: the "old" row is not automatically hidden, you can still see it with new value 2 among all the other rows with value 1.
5. You have to trigger the filter again manually to make the row disappear.

What can I do? I can't find a function to trigger the filter with current filter values.

Comment: Have you looked at the callbacks? Examples [Data](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/callbacks#data) Data Edited or [Cell](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/callbacks#cell) Cell Edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trigger the filter again you can use a combination of the ***getFilters*** and ***setFilter*** function:

```js
table.setFilter(table.getFilters());
```